# Pronunciation of i at the beginning of a word in French

Tags: prononciation, voyelles, nasalisation

Is it always/almost always the case the i at the beginning of a word followed by n in French is pronounced like the "nasal I" such as in cinq, and I before m at the beginning of a word pronounced like EE in fee ?
Much appreciated

Comment: Not always. "important" is pronounced [ɛ̃pɔʀtɑ̃(t)], therefore the IM in the beginning of the word has the same nasal sound of IN in this word. Usually IN and IM are pronounced [ɛ̃] when they are in the same syllable, regardless of their position in the word.

Answer (score 1):

[This probably isn't the most linguistically rigorous explanation, but I've found it to be the most helpful way to conceptualize the phonological rules involved.]

No, it depends on the exact phonetic structure of the word. Examples where an initial I succeeded by M is pronounced as a nasal (/ɛ̃/) are:

- *importun* ([ε ̃pɔ ʀtε ̃] or [ε ̃pɔ ʀtœ ̃]
- *important* ([ε ̃pɔ ʀtɑ ̃])
- *imbriquer* ([ε ̃bʀike])

Similarly, initial I succeeded by N may sometimes be pronounced as /i/, the non-nasal I:

- *inaperçu* ([inapε ʀsy])
- *inactualité* ([inaktɥalite])

(Pronunciations taken from the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr).) The general rule that I've observed is that the succeeding syllable is normally in a CV(C) structure. (In other words, the vowel of the syllable is to be preceded by a consonant, but a successive consonant is optional.) The initial *in-* or *im-* cannot be treated as a nasal vowel if the M or N is needed to supply the succeeding syllable with an initial consonant. To illustrate this with examples:

- *importun*: the syllable structure is *im-por-tun*. The vowel of the second syllable is preceded by /p/ so the M is part of the first syllable, and the first syllable is a nasal vowel.
- *immense*: for the purposes of this analysis, the syllable structure can be written as *i-(m)men-se*. The M is need to supply the second syllable with an initial consonant, so I is not pronounced as a nasal vowel.
- *inconnu*: the structure can be written as *in-co-(n)nu*. The consonant C is already attached to the second syllable. The N belongs to the first and the initial consonant is a nasal vowel. (Notice that this rule also explains why the vowel in the second syllable isn't nasal.)
- *inaptitude*: the structure is *i-nap-ti-tu-d(e)*. The N has to be attached to the second syllable as the second syllable will otherwise have no initial consonant. Thus, the I is not nasal.